# QML give focus to a Component

Tags: qt, qml

I have this code:

```
//main.qml
Window {
    id: root
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
    objectName: "Window"

    onActiveFocusItemChanged: console.log("***** ACTIVE FOCUS:", activeFocusItem, "*****")

    StackView {
        anchors.fill: parent
        initialItem: "qrc:/LoaderPage.qml"
        objectName: "StackView"
        onCurrentItemChanged: currentItem.forceActiveFocus()
    }
}


//LoaderPage.qml
Item {
    objectName: "ItemLoaderPage"
//    Keys.forwardTo: loader

    Loader {
        id: loader
        anchors.fill: parent
        objectName: "Loader"
        focus: true
        sourceComponent: rect1
    }

    Component {
        id: rect1

        Rectangle {
            Keys.onReleased: {
                if(event.key === Qt.Key_Escape || event.key === Qt.Key_Back)
                {
                    console.log("Esc or back pressed from", objectName)
                    event.accepted = true
                }
            }

            objectName: "Rectangle"
            focus: true
            color: "blue"
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to give the focus to the Rectangle in rect1 Component and catch key events, but with this code, the focus is always given to ItemLoaderPage and I am not able to catch key events. How can I solve that?

Answer (score 1):

I find that maintaining keyboard focus is a big weakness in Qt. The [docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-input-focus.html) make it all sound so straightforward, but in practice I am always ending up in situations where I can't even tell where the focus went.

I usually resort to manually calling forceActiveFocus() rather than depending on Qt to do the right thing automatically. It's a fragile solution, but it's at least one that I feel I have control over.

```
Loader {
    sourceComponent: rect1
    onLoaded: {
        item.forceActiveFocus();
    }
}
```

Comment: I've tried and the output is the following: qml: ***** ACTIVE FOCUS: QQuickRectangle(0xfc4a80, "Rectangle") *****
qml: ***** ACTIVE FOCUS: LoaderPage_QMLTYPE_1(0xfc52c0, "ItemLoaderPage") *****. So it is not working on my pc

Comment: That looks like it is working at first, but then something else changes focus back to the Loader.

Comment: Yes, the parent of the Component is taking the focus, I think it's because of the forceActiveFocus on the StackView

Comment: Yes, you're probably right. That points to the fragility of this solution that I mentioned above. The timing of the calls often results in the wrong item getting focused last. But I have not found any other solution that is better. I think Qt puts much more emphasis on mouse/touch screen input than on keyboard.

Comment: Yeah, it's not optimal. What we do is to keep repeating the mantra of "Never set focus to false, ever, anywhere", and 90 % of the time it keeps you on track.

Answer (score 0):

The Loader and the rectangle has requested the focus by your attribute:

```
focus: true
```

You should try to set the focus only once if I get the idea of the focus-attribute right.

Comment: I've tried but it's not working. The documentation https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-loader.html says to set focus on Loader and childs.